# Display given value in XY axis - Plotly

Tags: angular, graph, plotly

I am trying to display `1,1.5,4,7,9` in X axis and `2.5,1,5,3` in Y axis. When I tried to do this, my output is like `1, 1.5, 2, 2.5,......` which is basically breakdown of values which I have given. I want only values which I have given in XY axis and I don't want auto range(Scroll value).

Comment: Can you shows us the code which gave you this output? It is best to provide a [MCVE], chances of a getting an answer are much higher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using JavaScript since you tagged angular.

You are going to have to set three attributes to make this work: [tickvals](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#layout-xaxis-tickvals), [ticktext](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#layout-xaxis-ticktext), and [tickmode](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#layout-xaxis-tickmode). In the documentation you they tell you:

> **tickmode** ( enumerated : "auto" | "linear" | "array" )
>   Sets the tick mode for this axis. If "auto", the number of ticks is set via `nticks`. If "linear", the placement of the ticks is determined by a starting position `tick0` and a tick step `dtick` ("linear" is the default value if `tick0` and `dtick` are provided). If "array", the placement of the ticks is set via `tickvals` and the tick text is `ticktext`. ("array" is the default value if `tickvals` is provided).
>
> **tickvals** (data array) 
>   Sets the values at which ticks on this axis appear. Only has an effect if `tickmode` is set to "array". Used with `ticktext`.
>
> **ticktext** (data array) 
>   Sets the text displayed at the ticks position via `tickvals`. Only has an effect if `tickmode` is set to "array". Used with `tickvals`.

So `tickmode` says you want to use your own labels, `tickvals` says where to put those labels, and `ticktext` are your labels. Setting `tickvals` and `ticktext` should make Plotly infer `tickmode` so you should be able to omit this if you want. Using something like the following should help you achieve your goal:

```
var layout = {
    xaxis: {
        tickmode: "array",
        tickvals: [1,1.5,4,7,9],
        ticktext: [1,1.5,4,7,9]
    },
    yaxis: {
        tickvals: [1,1.5,4,7,9],
        ticktext: [1,1.5,4,7,9]
    }
}
```

[This example](https://plot.ly/javascript/axes/#enumerated-ticks-with-tickvals-and-ticktext) Should help.

Comment: How to set date time with interval of 3 hours  (i.e) 12AM, 3AM, 6AM..... for x axis?

Comment: You should be able to do that by setting ```tick0``` to your first time then setting ```tickd```. You will have to have set ```tickmode: "linear"```. [documentation](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#scatter-marker-colorbar-tick0)