# Plotly YAxis TickText Python - Text not appearing correctly

Tags: python, plotly, axis-labels

I am trying to change numerical values on a Plotly line graph using Dash from numeric numbers to text description and I can get it working for the first stick value but not the rest. I am trying to make the change on the Y Axis

Would appreciate thoughts on what I am doing wrong

```
stay_at_home = ['a','b','c','d']

fig_two =  px.line(top5_confirmed_cases, 
                   x=top5_confirmed_cases.Date.astype(str), 
                   y=policies, 
                   color='CountryName',
                   title=policies + ' in the top five countries',
                   labels={'x': 'Date'})
    
fig_two.update_layout(yaxis = dict(type='category',
                                       tickmode = 'array',
                                       ticktext=stay_at_home,
                                       tickvals=(top5_confirmed_cases['Stay at home requirements'])))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I misinterpreted  the purpose of 'tickvals'

This post helped me understand this better and resolve the issue

[Display given value in XY axis - Plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51324556/display-given-value-in-xy-axis-plotly)

Once I changed the following, this worked perfectly

```py
fig_two.update_layout(
  yaxis = dict(tickmode = 'array',
               ticktext=stay_at_home,
               tickvals=[0,1,2,3]))
```